# Documentation Search : google-like (pokygon -> polygon)

Tags: notebooks, text, documentation, system, searching

If you search for "pokygon" in google.com, then google automatically fix error, and searches for "polygon".

Like google.com, if you search for "pokygon" in mathematica (V 13.1) documentation search system, then it searches for "polygon". We see Mathematica has similar auto correction ability.

Where does such auto correction come from? If you know that then you can write it as an answer. Otherwise, if we assume that

> Assumption :
> Mathematica documentation search system is consist of built-in
> commands (documented or undocumented).

, then we can draw a following conclusion.

> Conclusion :
> There is a text search related built-in command that naturally has auto correction ability.  **or**
> Mathematica documentation search system is rather complex and built skillfully, so that it exhibits auto correction ability.

And also, I've tried

1. I created a folder and copied some original .nb documentation files (tutorial) to that folder.
2. I created search index for the files in that folder, using `CreateSearchIndex`
3. I tested whether `TextSearch` has google-like auto-correction ability or not.
4. `TextSearch` doesn't seem to have such auto-correction ability.

Ultimate goals are

1. understand the principle of auto correction ability in text search.
2. perform text search for documents(.nb or .txt...), having auto-correction ability.
3. The most ultimate goal is searching just like *the original documentation search system* for custom .nb or .txt files in custom location.

Comment: `nf = Nearest[DictionaryLookup[]]`. Usage: For example, to find `7` similar words, `nf["pokygon", 7]`. Perhaps a similar strategy is in place to find similar words during a search. Also try: `nf["polygon", 7]` to cover the case when there is an exact match. Explore the `EditDistance` function. `alist = nf["polygon", 50]` and `EditDistance["polygon", #] & /@ alist` .

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful and I understood all. Hope there is an answer for the principle of documentation searching system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following is roughly what the documentation search appears to use:

We first create an index:

```
index = CreateSearchIndex["ExampleData/Text"]
```

[image]

If we now search for `"lorep"`, we'll find nothing:

```
res = TextSearch[index, "lorep"]
```

[image]

We can however ask for suggested spelling corrections:

```
res["TermSuggestions"]
(* <|"FileName" -> {"lorep" -> "lorem"}, 
 "Plaintext" -> {"lorep" -> "lorem"}, "Title" -> {"lorep" -> "lorem"}|> *)
```

As you can see, it tells us that there would be results with a matching `"FileName"` tag if we replaced `"lorep"` with `"lorem"`, etc.

Using some more undocumented magic, we can automatically include spell-corrected search results:

```
res = Block[
  {TextSearch`PackageScope`$DisableQueryExpansion = True},
  TextSearch[
   index,
   SearchQueryString@ "lorep",
   "AutoApplySuggestionField" -> "Title"
   ]
  ]
```

[image]

Every part of this seems necessary, although I'm not entirely sure how they all work together to give the result we see. My guess is that the `"AutoApplySuggestionField"` setting tells it to apply the `"TermSuggestions"` setting from above, specifically the suggestions for `"Title"`.